# Bitbucket's Access Key Not Working

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am on EC2 - Amazon Linux AMI.

I want to be able to read (read-only) the repos from the EC2 machine. For this purpose, I created an SSH key inside the EC2 machine as follows

1. **ssh-keygen** (I enter password)
2. **ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa**
3. **ssh-add -l** (I get 2048 79:d3:f6...::53 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
4. **cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub** (I get the key)

Then, I copy paste the key in step (4) to Add Key

[https://bitbucket.org/[my--account]/[my-repo]/admin/access-keys/](https://bitbucket.org/%5Bmy--account%5D/%5Bmy-repo%5D/admin/access-keys/)

Then, I go back to the local machine (all in sudo)

1. mkdir [repo-name] && cd [repo-name]
2. git init
3. git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:[my-account]/[my-repo].git
4. sudo git pull

The output is

> sudo git pull
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

What is going on?

Comment: How did you copy-paste the key content? Perhaps you copied it with some whitespace/linefeed?

Comment: no, it looks fine, no whitespaces. i did copy paste with mouse.

Comment: Indeed, copy-paste from a SSH terminal (emulator) sometimes has this effect, because a line which exceeds the maximum number of characters that can be displayed in one row will be displayed on several (obviously). Can you download the file locally and open it with a text editor and retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, I go back to the local machine (all in sudo)

Why do you do it with `sudo`? You either create the keys under regular user and clone with regular user or do everything from `root` shell (`sudo -i`). Using the keys of different user is not simply possible.

Comment: you're such a legend :) "sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/folder" and then "git pull" is possible